# Strange problems with serial port comunicaiton

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, serial-port

I've two problem when working with serial port (COM) which I cannot find any reason for it:

1-I've wrote a program in c# (wpf) to receive data from a micro-controller(micro sends some data continuously with an interval ,e.g every 100 ms)  , when I run my program in visual studio it receives data but there are some delays in receiving the data; it receives the first three data then a delay and then some other data and continues this scenario without any discipline. I've tried both release mode and debug mode but no change. but when I go to Debug folder or Release folder and run the .exe from there every thing is ok and receives data continuously), I'm really confused!!

2-for connecting to micro I used usb-to-COM converter(cable with one side usb and other side COM port) . sometimes between the running of the program I disconnect the connection by pulling out the usb from my laptop(yet micro is sending) and when I connect it again to my laptop, mouse , app windows,... all move and I cannot control anything!

Comment: Without any code to look at  and without knowing which micro controller are you using, which kind of answer do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

A USB serial port cable is actually a device (usually classified as a USB to UART bridge device, there's actually a UART in one of the cable connectors). By pulling the USB cable from your laptop, you're effectively removing the serial port device from your system, meaning your COM port no longer exists. If you do this while your program is running, I'd expect the program to crash. A connection over a serial port is a file stream connected to \\.\COM#

'#' is just a placeholder, it could be COM4, COM5, etc. depending on how many other serial port devices are active on the system. What you're effectively doing is similar to disconnecting a harddrive while your program has a file open on that drive. I would not expect it to end gracefully.

As for the data reception, serial ports are very slow by today's standards while computer programs are very fast by serial port standards. Also, while serial port input can be implemented as a blocking call, it will eventually time out. When it times out you're probably reading a 0-byte if you don't check for a time-out condition.

All I can provide you with without knowing more detail of what it is exactly you're attempting to accomplish and how you're attempting to accomplish it.